# KeyInput, customizing, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a key listener thing for my game, it worked well.

Then I try upgrading the scripts to support them but I've used axises previously, they worked well but I want to make it so that it is one of the keys that you set.

I have this:

```
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyManager.instance.keyscode[0]))
        {
            flyfloat = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyManager.instance.keyscode[0]))
        {
            flyfloat = 1;
        }
```

This didn't work, it switches it doesn't have a smooth transition like the axis do.

What do I do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it.

so I changed the code to:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyManager.instance.keyscode[0]))
{
    flyfloat += .05f;
    flyfloat = Mathf.Clamp(flyfloat, -1, 1);
}
else
{
    flyfloat -= .05f;
    flyfloat = Mathf.Clamp(flyfloat, -1, 1);
}
```

Edit:
This adds 0.05 to the flyfloat when W is pressed and clamps it between -1 and 1 so that it won't go above and you can still control how fast you go, then it takes 0.05 when the key isn't pressed.